# Why won't div become visible when resizing window

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the display: none and visibility options in HTML/CSS

I have the scenario set up here
https://jsfiddle.net/vntkpus6/5/

```
HTML: 
<!doctype html>
<body>
<div class="grabber"></div>
</body>
</html>

CSS:
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .grabber {
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
.grabber {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: red;
    background-repeat: no-repeat
}
```

There must be something I must be missing, it seems like when I resize the window to 800px the square should become visible, yet it doesn't work.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: you have no opening html tag in your code. you might wanna fix that btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `@media` query below the `.grabber` rule set. What is happening is that your second definition of `.grabber` is overriding what is in the media query. It's just the way CSS works!

Answer (score 0):

You should to use min-width, it mean "if the width more than 800px use it"

```
@media (min-width: 800px) {
    .grabber {
        display: none;
    }
}

.grabber {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: red;
    background-repeat: no-repeat
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you should use media query after .grabber.Please let me know after doing in below way all things work perfectly or not.

**HTML CODE:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>OFFSET</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="grabber"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
.grabber {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: red;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
@media all and ( max-width: 800px) {
    .grabber {
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```